# How to set an IP whitelist on a NodeJS socket.io server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ip, whitelist

I'd like to restrict the connection to the socket server only to a list of IP, is there any simple way to do that? I couldn't find any so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following **@proxim0** post, I used a middleware :

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/config.json', function(err, file) {
        if(err) return next(new Error("Internal error : " + err.message));

        const config = JSON.parse(file.toString('utf8'));
        if(!config.restrictAccess) return next();
        
        var ip = socket.request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.request.socket.remoteAddress || null;

        if(ip == null || config.allowedAddresses.indexOf(ip) == -1) {
            console.log("Access denied from remote IP " + ip);
            return next(new Error("Your IP address is not allowed to access this resource."));
        }
        next();
    });
});
```

With a config.json file with the following format :

```
{
    "restrictAccess": true,
    "allowedAddresses": [
        "127.0.0.1",
        "123.456.789"
    ]
}
```

Any comment on improvment is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a few ways..

1. Put some middleware on the connect to read the incoming request IP, check it against an IP list (an array), if it does not work then respond with an error code.
2. Use an ACL via NGINX, if their IP is not listed, NGINX will block the request
3. Not really based on IP but, control access via JWT. This would require you to generate the token and send it with each request but it does provide a little more security and you won't have to manage IP ranges. In this architecture your user would request the token, once the token is sent back you make the request to the socket server with the token in the head or as a req param. The socket server then decodes it, if it decodes correctly (meaning it valid) then let them connect, otherwise don't